# Trabalhar com hora e minuto

Tags: javascript, data

Gostaria de fazer um código que pegasse hora e minuto para que eu possa trabalhar com uma programação de horários para a execução de uma ação, exemplo:

```
var inserirProgramAtual = document.getElementById("CBNestudio");

    if ((new Date().getDay() > 0) && (new Date().getDay() < 6)) { 
        if (new Date().getHours() >= 5 && new Date().getHours() <= 9) {
            inserirProgramAtual.innerHTML = `

        <span>Jornal da manhã</span>

    `
        } else if (new Date().getHours() >= 9 && (new Date().getHours() <= 10)) {
            inserirProgramAtual.innerHTML = `

        <span>Programa qualquer</span>

    `
```

Eu consegui pegar o horário normalmente, que é 9 horas, mas o que eu poderia fazer para pegar 30 minutos? Por exemplo, quero que às 9h10 ou 9h30 execute uma ação.

Comment: Por favor, explique de forma mais clara a sua dúvida.

Comment: Não é só chamar `getMinutes`? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes

Comment: Eu quero que a ação do código seja executado às 9h30, já tentei com getMinutes e não deu certo

Comment: Neste caso, concordo com o Wictor que não está claro o que vc quer e como está fazendo. Por favor clique em **[edit]** e explique em mais detalhes o que vc quer fazer e o que quer dizer "não deu certo" (deu algum erro? o código se comportou de maneira inesperada? qual? etc). Em outras palavras, tente fazer um **[mcve]**

Comment: Editei, caso ainda não ajude eu tento ser mais claro, desculpe a pergunta mal formulada.

Comment: Você esta pensando as informações de onde? E o que você quer fazer com esta informação?

Comment: O foco é a linha de código:
if (new Date().getHours() >= 5 && new Date().getHours() <= 9) {...}

Desejaria que o horário fosse 9:30, e não apenas 9:00 como o código já está fazendo.

Comment: Certo, dai o script iria ser acionado exatamente as 9:30. Quem iria ficar de olho no relógio e com dedo no botão do mouse para rodar o script no exato momento que  o horário marcar 9:30? Mais fácil fazer a condicional se a hora e minuto atual for maior que 9:30hs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for para somente não executar após o horário faça a verificação em duas etapas, conforme abaixo:

```js
let dateTime = new Date();

if(dateTime.getHours() >= 5 && dateTime.getHours() <= 9){
 if(dateTime.getHours() === 9 && dateTime.getMinutes() >= 30){
    console.log('vai parar');
   return false
  }
  
  console.log('Continua...');
}
```

Agora se precisar disparar o script no horário exato, recomendo ver sobre o uso de cron job.